# Capybara: Should I get rid of extracted constants or keep them?

Tags: cucumber, capybara, constants

I was wondering about some best practices regarding extraction of selectors to constants. As a general rule, it is usually recommended to extract magic numbers and string literals to constants so they can be reused, but I am not sure if this is really a good approach when dealing with selectors in Capybara.

At the moment, I have a file called "selectors.rb" which contains the selectors that I use. Here is part of it:

```
SELECTORS = {
   checkout: {
        checkbox_agreement: 'input#agreement-1',
        input_billing_city: 'input#billing\:city',
        input_billing_company: 'input#billing\:company',
        input_billing_country: 'input#billing\:country_id',
        input_billing_firstname: 'input#billing\:firstname',
        input_billing_lastname: 'input#billing\:lastname',
        input_billing_postcode: 'input#billing\:postcode',
        input_billing_region: 'input#billing\:region_id',
        input_billing_street1: 'input#billing\:street1',
    ....
}
```

In theory, I put my selectors in this file, and then I could do something like this:

```
find(SELECTORS[:checkout][:input_billing_city]).click
```

There are several problems with this:

- If I want to know the selector that is used, I have to look it up
- If I change the name in selectors.rb, I could forget to change it somewhere else in the file which will result in `find(nil).click`
- With the example above, I can't use this selector with `fill_in(SELECTORS[:checkout][:input_billing_city])`, because it requires an ID, name or label

There are probably a few more problems with that, so I am considering to get rid of the constants. Has anyone been in a similar spot? What is a good way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone mentioned the SitePrism gem to me: https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism

> A Page Object Model DSL for Capybara
>
> SitePrism gives you a simple, clean and semantic DSL for describing
>   your site using the Page Object Model pattern, for use with Capybara
>   in automated acceptance testing.

It is very helpful in that regard and I have adjusted my code accordingly.